# Why the child process is not executed?

Tags: c, unix, process, fork

I have the following piece of code:

```
int main() {
   int n = 1;
   if(fork() == 0) {
      printf("child");
      n = n + 1;
      exit(0);
   }
   n = n + 2;
   printf("%d: %d\n", getpid(), n);
   wait(0);
   return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I don't understand why the child process is not executing.

The child process is executing only if i set `sleep(1)` in the parent process

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know? The child doesn't do anything (observable).

Comment: @tkausl, i insert a printf command in the child process..see updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* getting executed and it should be outputting the text. No newlines should be necessary:

https://ideone.com/a1tznH

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
   int n = 1;
   if(fork() == 0) {
      printf("child");
      n = n + 1;
      exit(0);
   }
   n = n + 2;
   printf("%ld: %d\n", (long)getpid(), n); //this is how you should print pids
   wait(0);
   return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
child23891: 3
```

Perhaps you didn't notice the child text was at the beginning of your next prompt:

```
18188: 3
child[21:17] pskocik@laptop: $
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The program returns 3 because, the parent process didn't receive the child value, isn't it ?

Comment: That can be achived using pipe or fifo communication.

Comment: forked children get a (usually lazy, i.e. copy on write) copy of their parent's address space. The n in the child is a different n.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Everything gets copied. If you had called `printf("foo");` in the parent before forking, you would've gotten `foo` twice in the output because stdio's output buffer is included in "everything".  (But not if you printed "foo\n" because `\n` forces a flush of the buffer if the output file is a terminal).

Comment: I understand now perflectly how it works ! Thanks a lot !.

Answer (score 2):

The child is executed but two processes are trying to write on the same FD - STDOUT (File Descriptor).

If you want to see the result, put "\n" in printf of the child.

```
int main() {
   int n = 1;

   if(fork() == 0) 
   {
     printf("child\n");
     n = n + 1;
     exit(0);
   }
   n = n + 2;
   printf("%d: %d\n", getpid(), n);
   wait(0);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's my mistake! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();

if(pid < 0)
{
   printf("fail to fork");
}
else if (pid == 0)
{
    printf("running child");
    exit(0);
}
else
{
    print("running parent");
    wait(0);
    print("child done");
}

return 0;
```

This is the basic structure of a program I wrote recently which works. Not totally sure why yours didn't work though.